# How can I sold my software?

Tags: php, xampp, server

I don't know if I can ask this here but well.

I have created my software, it's developed in php 5.4, laravel 4, xampp v3.2.1, and I work the software local (localhost/public/something).

So my question is:
If I want to sell my software, how can I install it in the pc of a user?

I dont know about servers, but I think it's better to have the data in a free server isn't it? Any recommended tutorial?

I don't want to install the xampp server to the client and all the stuff of a developer, just install the software and have it easy for the user.

Any help will be grateful.

Comment: How do you expect your clients to be able to run .php scripts, talk to a database, etc.. if they DON'T have php/mysql/apache running locally?

Comment: Look into using ioncube encoding to keep your php code encrypted, before you offer it to a client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't sell PHP software with the expectation that a user installs it. This is functionally possible but involves so much setup that you'd never guarantee a user would be able to use it on even a small range of systems. They'd have to setup a web server, database server, all the various connections etc. or you'd have to write an installer which did all that for them.

You're also disclosing your entire code base to any user who buys your software, which means there are no mechanisms you could use to prevent both your software and code being shared freely - which is nice if you're writing open source, but not if you plan to make much money.

The best way to sell software in the form of a website is to provide a restricted user mechanism such that you can enable or disable a users' access via a website, and control this access based on a subscription or one time sale to the customer.

Answer (score 1):

You're speaking of xampp so it seems you have created a website/application. Hence you should not have to  "install it in the pc of a user". A website is made to be available from any machine with a browser.

Xampp is a local server on your computer. What you need is a server to make it available to other person than you.

You have a wide variety of possibilities to host your code and make it available:

- Shared hosting
- IaaS/PaaS hosting (http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/paas-providers,1-1517.html)

You'll also need a domain name to make it reachable (ex: stackoverflow.com)